# Worte, die gleich geschrieben werden, aber durch andere Aussprache eine andere Bedeutung haben

Tags: single-word-request

Wie nennt man Worte, die gleich geschrieben werden, aber durch andere Aussprache eine andere Bedeutung haben?

Zum Beispiel:

Montage, wie in: "Von allen Wochentagen mag ich Montage am liebsten."

Montage, wie in: "Der Bausatz bedarf einer komplizierten Montage."

Comment: Ein interessantes Beispiel wäre noch: *Sie feierten Hochzeit zur Hochzeit der Tourismussaison*. - Hier sehen wir ein Minimalpaar, dessen Differenzlaut ein "o" in mal langer, geschlossener, mal kurzer, offener Aussprache ist.

Comment: Vielleicht gefällt dir auch: "Die Häuser modern, modern sind sie nicht."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das nennt man ein **Homograph** oder **Homogramm**: ein Wort aus einer Gruppe von Wörtern, welche alle die gleiche Schreibweise, aber unterschiedliche Bedeutungen und häufig auch eine unterschiedliche Aussprache haben

Siehe auch: [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph)